# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' to 'NSString' in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, core-location

I am using CLLocationmanager to get the latitude and longitude from app delegate
by using the following code:

```
  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate{


    var window: UIWindow?

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var seenError : Bool = false
    var locationFixAchieved : Bool = false
    var locationStatus : NSString = "Not Started"


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    initLocationManager();
        return true
    }

    func initLocationManager() {
        seenError = false
        locationFixAchieved = false
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        if ((error) != nil) {
            if (seenError == false) {
                seenError = true
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if (locationFixAchieved == false) {
            locationFixAchieved = true
            var locationArray = locations as NSArray
            var locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as! CLLocation
            var coord = locationObj.coordinate
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(coord.latitude, forKey: "latitude")



            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(coord.longitude, forKey: "longitude")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            print(coord.latitude)
            print(coord.longitude)
        }
    }
```

While using the value from nsuserdefaults in map view by using the code

```
   latitude = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("latitude") as? NSString)! as String
        longitude = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("longitude") as? NSString)! as String
        let latitude1 = (latitude as NSString).doubleValue
        let longitude1 = (longitude as NSString).doubleValue
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: latitude1,
            longitude: longitude1
        )
```

I am getting error "Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x1944fb9f8) to 'NSString'" at `latitude = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("latitude") as? NSString)! as String`

Comment: `coord.latitude` is a `double`, not a `string`. So it's converted into a `NSNumber` when you save it into `NSUserDefaults`.  So this should do the trick: `let latitude1 = (latitude as NSNumber).doubleValue`

Comment: You're saving the value as a number and trying to read it back into a string.  What's the question, exactly?

Comment: Thanks the issue is fixed..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AppDelegate use this code to save the latitude and longitude in NSUserDefaults like this

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if (locationFixAchieved == false) {
        locationFixAchieved = true
        let locationArray = locations as NSArray
        let locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as! CLLocation
        let coord = locationObj.coordinate
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(coord.latitude, forKey: "latitude")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(coord.longitude, forKey: "longitude")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        print(coord.latitude)
        print(coord.longitude)
    }
}
```

And for fetching the value use this code in the viewcontroller file

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let latitude2 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("latitude")
    let longitude2 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("longitude")
    let latitude1  = latitude2!.doubleValue
    let longitude1 = longitude2!.doubleValue
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: latitude1,
        longitude: longitude1
    )


}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("longitude") is an NSNumber so you just have to do like this:

```
let latitude = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("latitude")
let longitude = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("longitude")
    let latitude1 = latitude.doubleValue
    let longitude1 = longitude.doubleValue
```

More, in the first place you can set the user default like this

```
let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 1.0
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble("latitude", forKey: "latitude")
```

Comment: It shows Cannot assign value of type 'AnyObject?' to type 'String'